# Label Text Formatting in Vaadin (word-wrap, line break)

Tags: css, label, vaadin, line-breaks

I am trying to display a long description text in Vaadin window using a Label component. The problem is that, the text format in the interface is a single line, or a none structured text with paragraph, even though the original text in the database is structured.

```
public Component buildDescription(){
    CssLayout descriptionLayout = new CssLayout();
    descriptionLayout.setSizeFull();
    Responsive.makeResponsive(descriptionLayout);
    descriptionLayout.addComponent(new Label("<h2>Description</h2>", ContentMode.HTML));
    descriptionLayout.addComponent(new Label(singlePatent.getDescription(), ContentMode.PREFORMATTED));
    return descriptionLayout;

}
```

I have tried to use all the content modes, with no success, ContentMode.HTML, TEXT. The content wraps to fit the container, but the with no structure, its alike a long sentence broke to next line, no formatting.

In the css I have tried

```
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

with no success.
I have attached some text that I used for testing.

Please help me how to achieve the proper text formatting in Vaadin.

NOTE: I have the attachments in the same [question I asked on Vaadin Forum](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9327917)

Comment: linebreaks are ignored, if you use `ContentMode.PREFORMATTED`? it might use the wrong font, but it should honour the linebreaks.

Comment: If I use ContentMode.PREFORMATTED then I get the result as the first image in the link above (Vaadin Forum). Default text font, but no document structure, its all concatenated.

Comment: then there is already something broken with your CSS, as `<pre>` would honour the line breaks. does some simple string like `"line\nbreak"` also not work with pre (might be the data after all)?

Comment: No, it does not work, but if I check the data text from firebug, i see the text with proper format.

Answer (score 0):

For line break you can use `ElementFactory.createBr()`.

**Example**

This code:

```
HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
layout.add("Example 1");
layout.add("Example 2");
```

Will give this result:
[image]

But this code:

```
HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
layout.add("Example 1");
layout.getElement().appendChild(ElementFactory.createBr());
layout.add("Example 2");
```

Will give this result:
[image]

or use html br component:

```
layout.add(new Html("<br/>"));
```